# Minimizing damage when looking for a job due to leaving the previous one after a month

Tags: resume, job-search, employment-gaps

About a month ago I was deceived into accepting a job where the job listing and the real job were light years apart. After realizing I wasn't going to be happy and failing to negotiate a better future I decided to give notice and move on.

The first thing I did was contacting the other companies that made me an offer before without success, so I had to start again the process of sending applications and interviewing. There is a problem though, because I didn't include this last job on my CV, I have a 1 month gap that seems to be the most interesting thing recruiters want to know about my 6+ years career.

I understand we live in a difficult time due to the pandemic, so what can I do to minimize damage other than being honest about the gap and reassuring that it is not going to happen to them when asked (provided they are reasonable employers)?

Comment: `so what can I do to minimize damage other than being honest about the gap` - Why would you not be honest about it? Why not just tell them that the job description and offer were not the same as the actual job?

Answer (score 3):

Tell the truth. But show that you have learned from the experience.

> I was deceived into accepting ...

The hiring decision is a two way street. If the company managed to "deceive" you, then you didn't do your home work properly. Portraying this entirely as the company's fault will backfire.

1. Explain where YOU went wrong and talk about what YOU should ave done differently in the interview  and research process,
2. Explain what you will be doing differently this time
3. Explain why you are confident that you are not going to walk out again after 1 month

Comment: Good old victim blaming

Comment: You are only a victim, if you choose to be one.

Comment: That statement in itself is the definition of victim blaming